# How to remote access Jetson Nano Orin running Ubuntu via VNC?

Tags: remote-access, vnc, nvidia-jetson-nano, vnc-viewer

I'm trying to access Jetson Nano Orin (Developer Kit) via OpenVNC. I need to access the device remotely sitting anywhere via IP address. Does anyone tried to access Jetson Nano Orin via OpenVNC or any other VNC?

I generated the ovpn file but when tried to access via client it fails saying no connection. I refer to the link [here](https://www.webhi.com/how-to/how-to-install-openvpn-server-on-linux-debian-11-12/)

Comment: You may try teamviewer: https://www.teamviewer.com/fr/download/linux/  or NoMachine: https://downloads.nomachine.com/download/?id=114&distro=ARM